# Lion Server updating php from 5.3 to 5.4

Tags: php

I am trying to update our PHP version (Current: 5.3.15) to the latest 5.4.16 i used this link for my Lion Mac [PHP Install](http://php-osx.liip.ch/) and all worked well.

So then i went onto our Mountain Lion Mac Server and did the same but its still showing via phpinfo page as 5.3.15 same if i do a php -v via the terminal.

i understand that this install places it into the usr/local area whereas i believe the server is getting the php etc from /usr/bin/php and not the local.

So how ca i update the main php scripting and not the local or link up the server to use the local updated version?

Answer (score 1):

Replace the default location with a link to the new version:

```
sudo mv /usr/bin/php /usr/bin/php.orig
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/php /usr/bin/php
```

Comment: i tried this changing the second line to the php path - sudo ln -s /usr/local/php5/bin/php /usr/bin/php and then did a php -v and i get the version 'PHP 5.4.15 (cli) (built: May 20 2013 14:34:36) ' great thanks but within my phpinfo page i am still getting version 5.3.15?

Comment: i have managed to get somewhere as its a mac server the apache config is in a different location os i added the line to it PHPIniDir '/usr/local/php5/lib/php.ini' and now the phpinfo page is showing the 'Loaded Configuration File' as '/usr/local/php5-5.4.15-20130520-143923/lib/php.ini' but again its still showing in the phpinfo as version 5.3.15, any ideas how to complete the task?

Answer (score 0):

What does your `$PATH` look like on the command line?  You need the path to your PHP binary in `/usr/local` to come before the path to the system's default installation of PHP.

One alternative would be to install PHP in the same place as the default version, thus overwriting it.

I'd be wary of only making a symbolic link from `/usr/bin/php` to your local version of PHP.  This might work for executing PHP scripts, but when it comes time to compile custom extensions and what not, it could confuse `phpize` and mess up your build process.